# How to write data to model

Tags: django

I've put together code to create/save profiles:

view.py

```
class ProfilePageView(FormView):
template_name = 'meal_delivery/profile.html'
form_class = ProfileForm
success_url = '/meal_delivery/profile'

def form_valid(self, form):
    profiles = Profile.object.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    if profiles:
        form.instance = profiles[0]
        form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Profile Updated')
    else:
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Profile Saved')
    return super(ProfilePageView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_initial(self):
    profiles = Profile.object.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
    if not profiles:
        return {}
    return {
        'first_name': profiles[0].first_name,
        'last_name': profiles[0].last_name,
        'address1': profiles[0].address1,
        'address2': profiles[0].address2,
        'city': profiles[0].city,
        'state': profiles[0].state,
        'zip_code': profiles[0].zip_code,
        'allergens': profiles[0].allergens
    }
```

form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
address1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
address2 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
state = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

CHOICES = tuple((o.pk, o.name) for o in Allergen.objects.all())
allergens = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'allergens']

def clean(self):
    pass
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)

user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
allergens = models.ManyToManyField(Allergen, related_name='profiles')
object = ProfileManager()
```

Creates profile if one does not exist, no problem.
However, when I go to  update the data, nothing updates, no errors are reported and if I check the form object, it shows the updated fields with the updated text. It just does not save the information to the dB.

The only other thing I've tried is, when updating, using obj=form.save(commit=False)....obj.save(). Of course, it didn't work either.

Comment: where do you catch the `form` from the `request`?

Comment: Instead of setting form.instance, try `obj = form.save(commit=False)` `obj.pk = profile[0].pk` `obj.save()`

Comment: AFAIK you have to pass `instance` at the time you instantiate the form. I'm not surprised if patching it in later during validation fails. Provide a` get_form` method to your FormView.